# How to check if BOTH valus are null

Tags: sql

I have table A

lets say it has 2 columns where the values can either be null or a number. I want to select only rows that have at least one of the columns not null:

```
x1   x2
NULL NULL (don't include)
6    NULL (include)
NULL 6    (include)
6    6    (include)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `coalesce()`

```
where coalesce(col1,col2) is not null
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use an `OR` condition:

```
select *
from the_table
where x1 is not null
   or x2 is not null;
```

Comment: I prefer this, as Zaynul's solution may mean index use is skipped, depending on the sophistication of the optimizer